# Find a non-constructible algebraic number of degree $4$ over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction

I cannot think of a non-constructible algebraic number of degree $4$ over $\Bbb Q$ so far. I wish if I can find such an example. Could some one tell me some such numbers with justification? Also I would like to know the track of working out such an example. Any help or reference would be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490879/is-the-real-root-of-x43-x-3-constructible

Comment: Given a quartic equation with integer coefficients, all its roots are constructible if and only if the resolvent cubic has a rational root.  Most quartic equations with integer coefficients do not have that feature, and there you are.

Answer (score 8):

Take an $S_4$ extension which is the splitting field of a quartic polynmial, say $f(x)=x^4-4x+2$ with splitting field $K$.  If the roots of $f(x)$ were constructible, then all the elements of $K$ would be constructible.  For $G$ a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$, the fixed field of $G$, $K^{G}$ has odd degree over $\Bbb{Q}$, so the elements of $K\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ can't be constructible.  From  Milne, Remark 3.26, *Fields and Galois Theory*.

Answer (score 3):

One problem which leads to such a number is [Alhazen's billiard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhazen%27s_problem).

Comment: When was it proven that the solution to Alhazen's problem is not soluble by construction even if the coefficients are constructible?

Comment: @MichaelEjercito It was Jack M. Elkin; see *A deceptively easy problem*, The Mathematics Teacher, Vol. **58**, No. 3, pp. 194–199.

Comment: I am giuessing Elkin figured out that the Alhazen quartic's resolvent cubic does not always have rational solutions. In particular, if the linear coefficient for a quartic equation is $c$ and the quartic coefficient is $a$, for all rational solutions $p/q$ of this cubic, $p$ and $q$ being coprime, $p$ is a factor of $c$ and $q$ is a factor of $a$.